# AngularJS directive matching

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume we have this JS code:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
 return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

and html code:

```
<div my-customer></div>
```

Can anyone tell me why we are matching directive with `div` using `my-customer` while we don't have this name anywhere in the code?

above code is from here[Developer Guide / Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: This is a common gotcha with everyone who is new to angular.  HTML is not case-sensitive and camelCase is the norm in JS since using - in a variable name means you can't reference it like someObj.my-customer so there is this normalization process between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalized

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives <-- this section in that page also explains about how directives are matched regarding stripping the x- or data- prefixes.

Comment: @shaunhusain Yes, you are correct! Thanks for improving the answer